# Python Image Manipulation

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, image-processing, pyqt4

I am loading in big, raw data files with python. It is a collection of images (video stream) that I want to display on an interface. As of now I am embedding a matplotlib graph by using the imshow() command. However it is very slow.

The fast part is reading the data itself, but splitting it in a numpy array matrix already takes 8 seconds for a 14MB file. We have 50GB files. That would take 8 hours. It's probably not the biggest problem though.

What the real problem is, is displaying the images. Let's say all images of the 14MB file are in RAM memory (I'm assuming python keeps it there. Which is also my problem with python, you don't know what the hell is happening). So right now I am replotting the image every time and then redrawing the canvas, and it seems to be a bottleneck. Is there anyway to reduce this bottleneck?

Images are usually 680*480 (but also variable) of a variable datatype, usually uint8. The interface is a GUI, and there is a slider bar that you can drag to get to a certain frame. An additional feature will be a play button that will go through each frames near real-time. Windows application.

Comment: Your question is missing far too much information for anyone to be able to help, or waste their time guessing. What size are your files in pixels by pixels? What is the basic data type - uint8, float64? Why do you need to load them all at once? What's *"an interface"*? What OS do you use?

Comment: Updated my answer with some additional info.

Comment: This does not sound like a good use-case for matplotlib. Even matplotlib's animation module will probably struggle. Check opencv or anything like that targeting real-time output.